# The martingales difference

Tags: martingales, conditional-probability

I have a question about martingales. 
$(X_n,F_n)$ is a martingale. 
$$D_n=X_n-X_{n-1}$$
Proof that each pair of $D_n$ are uncorrelated.

I have a solution that for $m<n$ we have:
$$ED_{m}D_{n}=E(E(D_{m}D_{n}|F_{n-1}))=E(D_mE(D_{n}|F_{n-1}))=0$$

I don't understand this part:
$$E(E(D_{m}D_{n}|F_{n-1}))=E(D_mE(D_{n}|F_{n-1}))$$
$D_m$ is obviously $F_n$ measurable. $D_m$ is limited? Because only then we can write such a equation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $D_m$ is limited ?

Comment: That exist $C$ that $|D_m|<=C$

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not need a uniform bound on $D_m$: all the written expectations are finite if for each $m$, $D_m^2$ has a finite expectation.